# Convert string inside an Object to int

Tags: java, android

I have android/java convert question.

I use onClick to take clicks on my imageViews and catch their tags (for example, android:tag="2"). After that, I need to convert that tag to int so that I can use it as a number to do some calculations.

I am trying to do it in this way:

```
public void onClick(View v) {       
        Object viewID =  v.getTag();
        int id =  ((Integer)viewID).intValue();
}
```

BUT, the problem is that I do not get int value inside my "id" variable. The error says:

> "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer".

Can you give me some other way to convert my tag inside "viewID" to int and put it inside "id"?

I am new to android and I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert to string then int

```
int id =Integer.parseInt( viewID .toString() );
```

Answer (score 4):

If I have not misunderstood you

```
int id = Integer.parseInt((String)viewID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Integer.parseInt` method

```
public void onClick(View v) {       
    int id = 0; // some default value 
    try {
        id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag());
    } catch (Exception ignored) { }
}
```

This code wouldn't crash if tag is not contain numbers

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {       
    Object viewID =  v.getTag();

    int id = -1;

    if(viewID != null) {
        try {
            id = new Integer(viewID.toString()).intValue();
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // wrong format
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpley use:

```
int i = (Integer) viewID ;
```

or, starting from Java 7, you can write:

```
int i = (int) viewID ;
```